# Windows 7 Ribbon licensing vs Office 2007 Ribbon licensing

Tags: windows-7, licensing, office-2007, ribbon, restriction

If I recall correctly one of the limitations of the Office 2007 Ribbon UI was that you cannot use it to compete with other MS Office products like Word or Excel.

Does this same restriction apply for the Windows 7 Ribbon UI?

Thanx.

Comment: This is a legal question, not a programming question. Take a copy of the licensing agreement to a qualified attorney in your jurisdiction, or ask Microsoft.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I shouldn't bother the SO community with questions such as this. I just thought that some programmer might shed some light on this matter. Besides, some programmers do care about licensing, and this question might be useful to some.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming itself. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/369450) for details, and the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is from the Windows Ribbon Development [newsgroup](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsribbondevelopment/thread/b43aa9cc-0aac-44b5-afb9-af66a9997225):

> Just like Windows common controls,
>   there are no unusual licensing
>   requirements involved when using the
>   Windows Ribbon framework in your
>   applications.

Here's more info on the [Windows Ribbon Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371191(VS.85).aspx) and also some UI [Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc872782.aspx).